# Shortcut to select matces cases in R studio

Tags: r

I have a large function with many lines. Some times I would like to update my function and to select all the codes that have the same names then do paste and copy for the selected code. However, I always to do it manually. I am wondering if there is a shortcut keyboard in Rstudio to do this trick.

For example, suppose I would like to select all codes with `llA` (the full line, e.g., `llA[[j]][[i]] <- -0.98`.

some codes here

```
    llA[[j]][[i]] <- -0.98
    luA[[j]][[i]] <- 0.98
  } else if (somethings){
    llA[[j]][[i]] <- 1e-04
    luA[[j]][[i]] <- Inf
  } else if (somethings) {

    llA[[j]][[i]] <- -Inf
    luA[[j]][[i]] <- -1e-04 

         .....
         .....
```

I have many lines.

Comment: Take a look at `??gsub` and `??str_replace`. They serve well with data.frames though I don't know if they like functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at **Rename in Scope** in [here](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2016/11/11/easy-tricks-you-mightve-missed/)

Comment: I understand how to rename my function. However, I would like to select all of the lines that have the same name.